# Como tratar un array bidimesional pasado por puntero ? C

Tags: c

Como dice el título como puedo tratar un array bidimensional pasado por puntero, un ejemplo para clarificar mi idea:

```
main()
{
char array[10][10];
llenar_array(array);
}

void llenar_array(char *array[])
{
 char registro[10] = "Cadena";
 //Sin punteros sería algo así array[0] = registro;
 *array[0] = registro;
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es pasar un array bidimensional tipo char a una función pero tratarla mediante punteros.
Cualquier respuesta sobre el manejo de arrays bidimensionales mediante punteros será agradecida.
Gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Esto representa un array en la pila o *stack*:

```
char array[3][3];
```

Tiene como característica fundamental que sus posiciones están contiguas en memoria:

```
0x100 | 0x101 | 0x102 | 0x103 | 0x104 | 0x105 | 0x106 | 0x107 | 0x108 | 0x109
    0 |     1 |     2 |     3 |     4 |     5 |     6 |     7 |     8 |     9
```

Sin embargo esto es un array de punteros:

```
char *array[];
```

La principal característica de este tipo es que lo primero que te encuentras en memoria es un puntero que te redirecciona a la posición donde se encuentra cada *fila* de datos:

```
0x100 | 0x101 | 0x102 | ... | 0x160 | 0x161 | 0x162 | ... | 0x240 | 0x241 | 0x242 | ...
0x160 | 0x240 | 0x300 | ... |     1 |     2 |     3 | ... |     4 |     5 |     6 | ...
```

Así pues no, esas declaraciones no son equivalentes. Lo que sí podrías hacer, si lo necesitas, es crear un array de punteros que encapsule el array de la pila, pero es un proceso que tienes que programar a mano:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(int* array[])
{
  for( int i=0; i<3; i++ )
    for( int j=0; j<3; j++ )
      array[i][j] = i*3 + j + 1;
}

int main()
{
  int array[3][3];
  int* wrapper[3];
  for( int i=0; i<3; i++ )
    wrapper[i] = array[i];

  func(wrapper);

  for( int i=0; i<3; i++ )
  {
    for( int j=0; j<3; j++ )
      printf("%d ",array[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Otra cosa que puedes hacer es encapsular la creación del array de punteros con una macro. Se pueden conseguir ejemplos más elaborados pero aquí tienes un ejemplo:

```
#define PREPARE_ARRAY(dest,source,SIZE1) \
{ \
  for( int i=0; i<SIZE1; i++ ) \
    dest[i] = source[i]; \
}

int main()
{
  int array[3][3];
  int* wrapper[3];

  // SIZE1 no puede ser inferido por el compilador... mala suerte        
  PREPARE_ARRAY(wrapper,array,3);

  func(wrapper);

  for( int i=0; i<3; i++ )
  {
    for( int j=0; j<3; j++ )
      printf("%d ",array[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: Creo que se te fue el [tag:c++] ¡Jajaja!

Comment: @NaCl cierto... mañana por la mañana lo arreglo... que despiste!!

Comment: @NaCl gracias por fijarte... ya lo he arreglado

Comment: A la perfección :P